# Mapping Error in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to use NHibernate to connect to a Northwind database. But for some reason, I am not able to load the Entity Type.

This is my Entity class

```
public class Product
    {
        public virtual Int32 ProductId { get; set; }
        public virtual String Desc { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Mapping

```
 <class name="Product" table="Products">
    <id name="ProductId" column="ProductId" type="Int32">
      <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Desc" column="ProductName" type="String" length="60">
    </property>
  </class>
```

I am getting the following error message

could not load an entity: [OracleLinq.Product#12][SQL: SELECT product0_.ProductId as ProductId0_0_, product0_.ProductName as ProductN2_0_0_ FROM Products product0_ WHERE product0_.ProductId=?]

Here is the stack Trace

```
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadEntity(ISessionImplementor session, Object id, IType identifierType, Object optionalObject, String optionalEntityName, Object optionalIdentifier, IEntityPersister persister)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader.Load(ISessionImplementor session, Object id, Object optionalObject, Object optionalId)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader.Load(Object id, Object optionalObject, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Load(Object id, Object optionalObject, LockMode lockMode, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.LoadFromDatasource(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.DoLoad(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.Load(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.OnLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ImmediateLoad(String entityName, Object id)
   at NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.Initialize()
   at NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.GetImplementation()
   at NHibernate.Proxy.Poco.Castle.CastleLazyInitializer.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at ProductProxy4c67cf5bf6e640ab82d8c21a90e2a62b.set_Desc(String value)
   at OracleLinq.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Is there an inner exception inside the exception?

Comment: Usually whenever I get this nhibernate error, I try and copy and paste the SQL (With the parameters replaced) in Sql Management studio to make sure that I didn't do something silly and misspell a column.

Answer (score 1):

Second try:

Here is you configuration from your comments, just for readability:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(); 
cfg.Configure(); 
cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Product).Assembly); 
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory(); 

IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;"); 
ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(conn); 

Product product = (Product)session.Load(typeof(Product), 12); 
product.Desc = "";
```

It's clear that NHibernate has the mapping file, it could not have generated the query.

It could be that

- **the database is not there** : you already checked this.
- **the table is not there** : open a sql console (using the same connect string) and copy-paste the sql from the error message into it. Does it work?
- **the connection is not opened** : see bollow

I think that you need to open the connection yourself. Even better you let NHibernate create and manage the connections.

Try this:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(); 
cfg.Configure(); 
cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Product).Assembly); 
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory(); 

ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(); 

Product product = (Product)session.Load(typeof(Product), 12); 
product.Desc = "";
```

the connectstring goes to the nhibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider, NHibernate</property>
<property name="connection.connection_string">
 Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;
</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your connection string defaulting to the correct database? Check that it has Initial Catalog= [DB name here]

Comment: Yes. I am able to open the DB Connection. 

Here is the code which I am using 
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure();
cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Product).Assembly);
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(conn);
Product product = (Product)session.Load(typeof(Product), 12);
product.Desc = "";

Comment: Have you set your HBM file to be embedded in the assembly when it gets compiled?

Answer (score 0):

This should actually only be a problem when inserting, but you could also get troubles with it:

I think "identity" is not supported by oracle, it is a SqlServer feature (an auto-counting primary key). Oracle uses sequences.

Try the following (check the name of the sequence, which must exist)

```
<id name="ProductId" column="ProductId" type="Int32">
  <generator class="sequence">
    <param name="sequence">product_seq</param>
  </generator>
</id>
```

Or an other id generator. Hilo or Guid are interesting alternatives. See http://barchitect.blogspot.com/2008/07/nhibernate-generator-and-primary-key.html

Comment: No.. The error occurs even with Sequence column in Oracle. 
The error occurs also in SQL Northwind database with Generator as native or identity or hilo or guid.

Answer (score 0):

In your stacktrace, I see `ProductProxy4c67cf5bf6e640ab82d8c21a90e2a62b.set_Desc(String value)`, which means the error occurs when you set the 'Desc' property. This is the moment NHibernate tries to load the product from the database.

In your database you don't have a product with the id you supplied to Session.Load. If you use Session.Get, you'll probably get null.