# Pass a Guid to NHibernate's ISession.Get<T> method

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2008, guid

I'm experiencing with NHibernate 3.1.0 (without Fluent yet) on an existing solution in VS2010. Our DB is MsSql 2008 (I'm using NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect in the cfg.xml file).
I have an ValidationActivity object which I'd like to get from the DB. It has an ActivityID column of type uniqueidentifier (in the DB) / Guid (in the business object).
I've been following Summer Of NHibernate's 1st session so my provider is:

`public ValidationActivity GetActivityById(Guid activityGuid)

        {

            var sessionFactory = new configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();

            var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

            return session.Get<ValidationActivity>(activityGuid);

        }`

My mapping uses the guid generator:
`<id name="ActivityID" type="Guid">

      <generator class ="guid"/>

    </id>`

To test that, I created a test that tries to get an activity with a known Guid (one that I've inserted manually) as follows:
`NHibernateDataProvider provider = new NHibernateDataProvider();

            Guid guid = new Guid("885f380d-c6e3-459e-8cff-10f96f26cc0a");

            Activity testActivity = provider.GetActivityById(guid);`

The exception thrown is 'Could not load entity' with the following SQL string:
`SELECT validation0_.ActivityID as ActivityID0_0_, validation0_.ActivityName as Activity2_0_0_, validation0_.CreationDate as Creation3_0_0_, validation0_.Owner as Owner0_0_, validation0_.Project as Project0_0_, validation0_.Step as Step0_0_ FROM Activities validation0_ WHERE validation0_.ActivityID=?`

It seems to me that the '?' at the end is wrong, but I don't know what am I doing wrong.
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this post with a similar problem:
[Mapping Error in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773854/mapping-error-in-nhibernate)

Have you tried to run the query above replacing the ? with the actual guid in the database that this test is hitting? Are all the column/table names the same?  Seems like it could be a mapping issue.

Comment: It was a mapping issue - the CreationDate of the Activity was never initialized, and I found that out when I tried to save. Thanks!
Couldn't run the query with real Guid instead of '?' - got Invalid column name '885f380d-c6e3-459e-8cff-10f96f26cc0a' (this is the Guid). Never mind that anyway, thanks again!